# filter dataframe by int value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
    plz error  turn off 
0   11  1     Störung bei Paketabtransport  
1   11  1     Störung bei Paketabtransport  
2   11  0     Störung bei Paketabtransport  
3   127 3     Sicherheitstür (0SS5c.2) bei 
4   11  0     Störung bei Paketabtransport
```

I want to filter the df after the 0's in column 'error' ,how can I get a new df with the 0's and its corespondings rows ?

`df = df['error'] < 1` basically like this but only adding the coresponding rows

Comment: `df[df['error'].eq(0)]`  or `df[df['error'].eq(0).cumsum()>0]`?

Comment: could you show your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[11,0,'txt'],[11, 1, 'txt'],[11, 1, 'txt'], [11, 0, 'txt']], columns = ['plz', 'error', 'turn_off'])
>>>
    plz  error turn_off
0   11   0     txt
1   11   1     txt
2   11   1     txt
3   11   0     txt

new_df = df[df['error'] == 0]
>>>
    plz  error  turn_off
0   11   0      txt
3   11   0      txt
```